# Will Enceladus run out of water due to it being lost to space?

Tags: planetary-science, saturn, enceladus

The global liquid water subsurface ocean within Enceladus has been identified as being the primary source of material for Saturn's E-ring. Given that the moon is permanently ejecting large quantities of water to space through the south poles how long will this ocean continue to survive?

Comment: This question is probably more suited to Astronomy.SE. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enceladus it has a *lot* of water. Earth will probably lose its oceans long before Enceladus does.

Comment: And also it would collect it's own ejected water, to some degree

Comment: @AntiElonGuy indeed, in [Enceladus; why use the words "geysers", "jets", and "plumes" interchangeably?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/19939/7982) I mention an escape velocity of only 240 m/s. That means that a lot of the ejecta droplets and ice particles will rise high but fall back down again in an hour or so (if they don't evaporate/sublimate). However, that's the same order as thermal velocity of water vapor at the surface, so some vapor molecules could leave forever ballistically.

Comment: different but slightly related: [How can "Geysers" on Europa reach heights of 100km?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/18496/7982) and also [Is there an established distinction between a geyser and a cryovolcano in solar system bodies?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/19943/7982)

Answer (score 2):

**No.**
The approximate escape rate of water on Enceladus to space is $\rm \dot{m}_{\rm H2O}\approx 5000\; g\;s^{-1}$ ([ref](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019103521004565), with a factor 10 uncertainty in that number). Ganymedes icy mass $\rm m_{H2O}$, which I simply estimate at about 50% of its total mass would then need about $\rm m_{H2O}/\dot{m}_{H2O} \approx$ 400.000 billion years to escape, or about 30.000 times the age of the universe. In other words, Ganymedes water content at the current escape rates is stable.

Comment: The question asks about Enceladus. You first mention Enceladus & then discuss Ganymedes. Is there an error?

Comment: @Fred Woops, it seems so.. when researching the material my thoughts must have jumped from one icy moon to another..

Comment: Is that a decimal point, or a thousands separator? According to Wikipedia, Enceladus is losing water at a much higher rate than what you gave for Ganymede:~200 kg/s (it ejects ~250 kg/s of salty water, but much of the salt content falls back).

Comment: @PM2Ring A thousands separator. The same calculation with Enceladus' mass and your quoted escape rate gives a total lifetime of 0.6 ages of the universe. So then the answer would be "Yes, but it's gonna take a while".